# Storing id in arrays and using it for printing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I am actually new to coding. I am trying to make a barcode scanning app and which can scan multiple barcodes. So i am trying to store all the data in an array `code[]`  and i am printing the data in a html. I have defined the `code[]` array and a counter in different js file as

```
localStorage["counter"]=0;
var code = new Array();
localStorage.setItem("code", JSON.stringify(code)); `
```

and here is my `page5.html` file . In the following code `myvalue` is value getting from different code. The problem is with `myvalue1`. I am trying to call function again and again to get different value of `myvalue1` and store it in array `code[]`

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.4.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="barcodescanner.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div ng-controller="controller">
            <table ng-repeat="result in results">
                <tr>
                    <td>S.No</td>
                    <td>Barcode</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td id="d"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td id="code[0]"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td id="code[1]"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input class="butt" type="button" value="New Scan" onclick="scanCode();" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var barcodeVal = localStorage.getItem("myvalue");
        document.getElementById("d").innerHTML = barcodeVal;
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var scanCode = function() {
            window.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(

            function(result) {

                alert("Scanned Code: " + result.text + ". Format: " + result.format + ". Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
                localStorage.setItem("myvalue1", result.text);
                window.location.href = 'page5.html';

                var barcodeVal = localStorage.getItem("myvalue1");
                var test2 = localStorage.getItem("code");
                code = JSON.parse(test2);
                var k = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("counter"));

                alert(k);

                $("#code[k]").text(barcodeVal);

                k++;
                localStorage["counter"] = k;
                localStorage.setItem("code", JSON.stringify(code));

            }, function(error) {
                alert("Scan failed: " + error);
            });
        }
    </script>
    </html>
```

I dont know where am i going wrong and my array is not able to print the data in the table.
Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You're missing several closing tags, and have a `script` declared outside the `body`.

Comment: why cant I declare a `script` outside a `body` ?

Comment: My code in script is running fine. Just I am donno why is it not printing the value.

Comment: You set myValue1 and try to get myvalue!

Comment: myvalue is the one i am getting from different code. myvalue1 is giving me problem. i am getting the value of myvalue1 and i am trying to call myvalue1 again and again and tryin to store it in code[] array

Comment: I think you redirect to page5 messes it up

Comment: page5 is the same html file.

Answer (score 0):

your jquery selector is wrong instead of

```
$("#code[k]").text(barcodeVal);
```

it should be

```
$("#code["+k+"]").text(barcodeVal);
```

to work properly. And i couldn't get what r u tryin to do where u are updating the array. I hope this helps.

Comment: I am trying to store data in an array `code[]` and everytime i scan a new barcode I am trying to increment the counter by 1 so that i can that value separately in array . Finally i am trying to print all the values in the table using id stored in array. Is something wrong?

Comment: Can you please help me? After changing this also it isnt working.

Comment: @Raunak try declaring array like this var code = {};

Comment: I tried this as well but still the value corresponding `id= "code[0]"` is not printing.

Comment: Can u tell me how should i store an id corresponding to particular in an array like getelementbyid()innerHTML type. When i use inner html its showing some error. What should i replace it with?

Comment: @Raunak is your localstorage stores values properly check that

Comment: @Raunak can you create a jsfiddle with this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56403/discussion-between-sathya-raj-and-raunak).

Answer (score 0):

YOu can simply do it as below.

```
function SaveDataToLocalStorage(barcodeValue)
{

    var oldItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('barcodes')) || [];
    var newItem = {
        'barcode': barcodeValue
    };
    oldItems.push(newItem);
    localStorage.setItem('barcodes', JSON.stringify(oldItems));

}
var scanCode = function () {
      window.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(function (result) {
         if(result.cancelled == true ) {
           window.location.href = 'page5.html';
         } else {
           // below function save your data in localstorage.
           SaveDataToLocalStorage(result.text);
           scanCode();
         }

     }, function (error) {
            alert("Scan failed: " + error);
           window.location.href = 'page5.html';
    });
  }
```